# Common variable for all nodes in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to keep a common global variable for all my Map-functions in my Hadoop map reduce program.This variable is icremented inside of all the  map-functions,how do I do this synchronously?

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop is a "shared nothing" architecture and while there are ways around this to share some data between mappers or reducers, no way to guarantee synchronization. That being said, if you wanted to try, you could use a job counter to check the value. Alternatively, you could try changing your key type and set the number of reducers to 1. You could then guarantee that all of the data is see in by a single system and could apply your counter there. However, this depends on how big your data is.

Comment: Will having 1 reducer slow down my computaion to as good as processing on one node as map outputs have to queue up for that reducer?

Comment: Yes it will slow down your computation speed, which is why I said its potential as an alternative depends on how large your dataset is that gets reduced. Its one of those things that you have to decide if the tradeoff is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

User defined Counters are global: the Map-reduce framework aggregates
them across all maps and reduces to produce a grand total at the end of the job.

Create a counter in driver

```
public class Driver{
    enum Count {
        TOTAL
    } 
}
```

add below line in your mapper

```
context.getCounter(Count.TOTAL).increment(1);
```

Then Read counter value using below code after your job.submit()

```
Counters counters = job.getCounters();
long missing = counters.findCounter(
Driver.Count.MISSING).getValue();
```

This way using counters you can keep track of you global counter. This should server your purpose as my understanding goes.

Comment: but in this method, is Count synchronous?

Comment: Basically all the increment details will be send by Tasktrackers to Jobtracker which will consolidate the increments once the job is done.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is i have to access the incremented varible's value inside my mapper!

Answer (score 0):

Like TheCowSaysMoo said, Hadoop is shared nothing. You can use a database such as hbase in order to get a synchronous counter. See [increment](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#increment%28org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Increment%29) for more information.
I don't know if it's not an overkill for what you're up to, but that's one of hBase's uses.